# Notification "create-tag-synonym" badge - but don't have earned it

Tags: bug, status-completed

Received notification of "create tag synonym" privilege:

[image]

but neither have the badge, nor the necessary reputation...?

Additionally:
clicking on the notification takes me to [Help Center > Privileges > View Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)
??

Answer (score 7):

There was a large refactoring in the privileges code that was turned on today.

A bug was introduced where the privilege name was always shown as "create tag synonyms" in the achievements dialog, instead of the correct name (in this case, view close votes).

This has now been fixed.

---

From you reputation history, it appears that you have briefly had +250 reputation (yesterday), which is why you were notified of the privilege.

Comment: These changes are documented... where? OH, is just refactoring, not changing. *moving on*